# I have a function that takes a string as a parameter.vManually inputing a string works however using a scanf doesn't

Tags: c, scanf, strcmp

So I have this function that goes as follows `f(char * str)`. The string argument is a file name that is accessed using another function. So if I do `f("grille1.txt")` the program works as expected. However, if I do

```
char * filename;
scanf("%s", filename);
f(filename);
```

the program doesn't work as expected. So I concluded that the issue is with the `scanf`. However I tried doing

```
printf("%d Are they equal?", !strcmp(filename, "grille1.txt"));
```

and I get a 1 as a result which means that they are indeed equal so what could the issue be that results in using the variable `filename` not giving the same results as manually using `"grille1.txt"`?

Comment: What do you expect to happen after the user input? Sidenote: `scanf("%s",filename);` is unsafe. Don't.

Comment: What's your understanding of the line `char * filename;`?

Comment: The compiler should be warning you that `scanf("%s",filename);` is using an *uninitialised pointer*. That is, there is no memory allocation.

Comment: The behaviour you observe with [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) is undefined, because that function expects null terminated strings, and you have passed in an unknown string (`filename`) as one of the parameters

Answer (score 2):

The function `scanf` requires the address of a sufficiently large memory location where it should write the string, and you are supposed to pass the address of that memory location as a parameter to `scanf`. However, you are instead passing an uninitialized (garbage) value. This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Therefore, I suggest that you change the lines

```
char * filename;
scanf("%s",filename);
f(filename);
```

to:

```
char filename[100];
if ( scanf( "%99s", filename ) == 1 )
    f( filename );
```

In the code above, the declaration

```
char filename[100];
```

will allocate an array of 100 characters, which is sufficient to store 99 characters and the terminating null character. When passing `filename` to `scanf`, the array will [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer to the address of the first character of the array.

I enclosed the `scanf` function call inside an `if` statement, because it is generally a good idea to check the return value of `scanf`, to make sure that the function was successful.

Also, I am using the `%99s` format specifier instead of `%s` to limit the input to 99 characters, otherwise a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) would occur if the user enters more than 99 characters.

Comment: Definite kudos for pointing out `"%s"` is no safer than `gets()` unless the *field-width* modifier is used to prevent overflow.